# Validate using a specific definition with ajv

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I have a JSON Schema file describing my API. It consists of some definitions as well as some vestigial parts from codegen that I'd like to ignore (the `properties` and `required` fields):

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "CreateBook": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {"type": "string"},
        "author": {"type": "string"},
        "numPages": {"type": "number"}
      },
      "required": ["title", "author"]
    },
    "CreateShelf": {
      "properties": {
        "books": {"type": "array", "items": {"type": "string"}}
      },
      "required": ["books"]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "/api/create-book": {
      "properties": {"type": {"post": {"$ref": "#/definitions/CreateBook"}}},
      "required": ["post"],
      "type": "object"
    },
    "/api/create-shelf": {
      "properties": {"type": {"post": {"$ref": "#/definitions/CreateShelf"}}},
      "required": ["post"],
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "required": ["/api/create-book", "/api/create-shelf"],
  "type": "object"
}
```

I'd like to validate requests according to the definitions. I'd like to completely ignore the `properties` and `required` fields, which describe the shape of the API itself, not the individual requests.

Given what I expect to be a `CreateBook` request and this JSON schema, how should I validate it?

Here's what I tried:

```js
const ajv = new Ajv();
const validate = ajv.compile(jsonSchema);

const body = {
  author: 'Roald Dahl',
  numPages: 234,
  // missing title
};

if (!validate(body, '#/definitions/CreateBook')) {
  console.log(validate.errors);
}
```

This logs:

```
[
  {
    keyword: 'required',
    dataPath: '#/definitions/CreateBook',
    schemaPath: '#/required',
    params: { missingProperty: '/api/create-book' },
    message: "should have required property '/api/create-book'"
  }
]
```

So it's ignoring the `dataPath` parameter (`'#/definitions/CreateBook'`). What's the right way to do this? Do I need to create a new schema for every request type?

Answer (score 8):

If you use `addSchema` instead of `compile` to compile the schema, you can specify a fragment.

```
const ajv = new Ajv();
ajv.addSchema(jsonSchema);
const validate = ajv.getSchema("#/definitions/CreateBook");

const body = {
  author: 'Roald Dahl',
  numPages: 234,
  // missing title
};

if (!validate(body)) {
  console.log(validate.errors);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `$id` is not required, `ajv.getSchema('#/definitions/CreateBook')` works fine. Since `validate` is specific to `CreateBook`, I assume the second param to `validate` on the last line is meaningless. Is it OK to have many validators out at once (one for each endpoint)? I believe ajv keeps track of some state on the `ajv` object itself, so I could imagine this causing trouble.

Comment: Ahh, I guess you don't need an `$id` unless you need to add more than one schema. Yes, the extra argument to the validate function is not correct. I was modifying your original code and I missed that one. I'll edit the answer to fix those things.

Comment: "Is it OK to have many validators out at once". Yes, it's fine. If you need to add more than one schema, you'll need to give them `$id`s to distinguish between them. Also, once a validator is compiled, it's just a standalone function that is no longer dependent on ajv state.